# Limits and Puiseux series expansions

Tags: limits, reference-request

This is a follow-up to my [infinite sum question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1739603/what-is-the-infinite-sum). I'm now faced with calculating:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left( 5n+3 \right) \left( 1 - \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(\frac{3}{6})_k}{(\frac{13}{6})_k}\right)$$

WolframAlpha says it's $\infty$, and I would tend to believe it. But I have no clear idea how to get there... WA also provides a Puiseux series expansion:

$$\frac{30 n^{1/3} \Gamma\left(\frac{13}{6}\right)}{7 \sqrt{\pi }}-\frac{26 \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{2/3} \Gamma\left(\frac{13}{6}\right)}{21 \sqrt{\pi }}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{7/6}\right)$$

My first question here will be: do I understand correctly that the first term in that above sum behaves like a cubic root, and the two other terms tend to zero, as $n$ tends to $\infty$?

Second request: I wouldn't be surprised if getting to this Puiseux expansion is a rather long and tedious calculation, so I'm not expecting anyone to provide it. Therefore I'd be grateful for pointers to references (online ones if possible) that could help me understand and do the derivation myself.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achille's Hui approach to your other question through the Beta function is very powerful, but for the actual task the [Stolz-Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) is enough:

$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{1-\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_k}{\left(\frac{13}{6}\right)_k}}{\frac{1}{5n+3}}=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{-\frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_{n+1}}{\left(\frac{13}{6}\right)_{n+1}}}{\frac{1}{5n+8}-\frac{1}{5n+3}}. $$